# Checking whether string is empty, contains int or is an integer

Tags: c#, string, validation

I need to ask the user for his name, surname and other details and I wan't to verify them, basically checking if the string is empty, is an integer, or contains an integer. The problem with this code is let's say I type in "a" it works. And if I type in a2 it shows the correct error message but when I go to type in "a" on its own it keeps repeating the same error message. Any help would be appreciated and a cleaner way to write this would also be appreciated as I have to do this for the surname, email and other fields.

```
        bool check = true;
        Console.Write("Enter your name:");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
        bool isIntString = name.All(char.IsDigit);
        bool containsInt = name.Any(char.IsDigit);


        while (check == true) { 
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be empty");
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if(isIntString)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name cannot be made up of numbers");
                Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (containsInt)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Your name cannot contain numbers");
                Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if(!isEmpty && !isIntString && !containsInt)
        {
           check = false;
           Console.WriteLine("Name filled");

        }
    }


            Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Names can contain numbers. Yes, really: https://www.linkedin.com/in/m3sweatt/

Comment: Negative integers?

Comment: @IanMercer, Thanks for letting me know, in my case names won't contain numbers :)

Comment: When doing console Input, I always pick the do...while loop. It seems to be made for those "repeat until the user starts making sense" console inputs.

Comment: I'll try implement it @Christopher, thanks!

Comment: So you were stepping through the code in the debugger and entered the second name ("a"). You checked the values of the variables and ... ? Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With small changes to your code:

```
string name;

while (true)
{ 
    Console.Write("Enter your name:");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
    bool isIntString = name.All(char.IsDigit);
    bool containsInt = name.Any(char.IsDigit);
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be empty");
    }
    else if (isIntString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your name cannot be made up of numbers");
    }
    else if (containsInt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your name cannot contain numbers");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Name filled");
       break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
Console.ReadKey();
```

With variable term:

```
static string GetUserInput(string term)
{
    string name;

    while (true)
    { 
        Console.Write($"Enter your {term}:");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
        bool isIntString = name.All(char.IsDigit);
        bool containsInt = name.Any(char.IsDigit);
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot be empty");
        }
        else if (isIntString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot be made up of numbers");
        }
        else if (containsInt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot contain numbers");
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"Your {term} filled");
           break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Your {term} is: {name}");
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly also. If I had to create a method then change name to surname etc how would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Added it is a method which can be called with `var firstName = GetUserInput("first name"); var surname = GetUserInput("surname");`.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the input, you are checking for null/empty/integers.

```
bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
bool isIntString = name.All(char.IsDigit);
bool containsInt = name.Any(char.IsDigit);
```

However, these checks are placed outside the loop. Once evaluated, the 3 verification variables never changes, even after new input has been read.

For fixing the same, you need to place the checks within the loop.

```
  while (check == true) { 
        bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name);
        bool isIntString = name.All(char.IsDigit);
        bool containsInt = name.Any(char.IsDigit);
   // rest of code
```

To clean up code, you could refactor out the expressions and reading input to create a pattern, which could be reused for other inputs. For example,

```
void Main()
{
    bool check = true;
    var name = ReadInput("Enter your name:",ValidationExpressionsForName);
    // var surname = ReadInput("Enter your SurName :",ValidationExpressionsForSurName);
    // so on
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
}

public string ReadInput(string inputMessage,Func<string,IEnumerable<EvaluationExpression>> evaluationExpression)
{
    while (true) 
    { 
        Console.Write(inputMessage);
        string term = Console.ReadLine();

        if(evaluationExpression(term).Any(x=>x.Expression()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(evaluationExpression(term).First(x=>x.Expression()).Message);
        }
        else
            return term;

    }

}

public IEnumerable<EvaluationExpression> ValidationExpressionsForName(string message) => new EvaluationExpression[]
{
    new EvaluationExpression{ Expression = ()=>String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message), Message= "Name cannot be empty"},
    new EvaluationExpression{ Expression = ()=>message.All(char.IsDigit),Message ="Your name cannot be made up of numbers"},
    new EvaluationExpression{ Expression = ()=>message.Any(char.IsDigit),Message="Your name cannot contain numbers"}
};

public class EvaluationExpression
{
    public Func<bool> Expression{get;set;}
    public string Message{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I'm so stupid, this fixed it, thanks. Since I need to ask for more fields, should I make a method and just change name to surname etc? Thanks

Comment: @UweKeim I guess that wasn't the query OP had. It was more directed towards the particular behavior his code had.

Comment: @UweKeim, yes, negative integers display the "name can't contain numbers" message.

Comment: @AnuViswan how would I go about implementing a method, or shouldn't I?

Comment: @OldRunescapeCharacter I have updated the answer with a pattern which you could reuse. Please check

Comment: @OldRunescapeCharacter made another refactoring of the method. Possibly this would make better reuse of code

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a string is Null, Empty or WhiteSpace is relatively easy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace

Checking if it is a Number can be done. Just feed it to [Int32.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) and see if it can make sense of the input.

If it contains a anumber? Checkable, but not easily. You could itterate over all Characters in the string and check if any of them parse to Int. Note that this cheeck would supersede/make unessesary the previous check too. I made it into a simple function:

```
public bool IsValidName(String input){
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)){
        return false;
    }

    foreach (char current in input){
        int ignore;
        //TryPrase will not take Chars, but turning it into a string should be this easy
        String currentString = current.ToString();
        if(Int32.TryParse(currentString, out ignore))
            return false;
    }
    //You only get here if none of hte false cases was trigerred
    return true;   
}
```

All of this might be solveable with a single Regular Expression too, but I am not that good at Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails here. It goes into this else block displays the error message and then reads from the console again. while **`check`** still being `true` and `isIntString` still `true` it again lands up in this block. You need to correct it for all the three checks you have placed on the the string.

```
  else if(isIntString)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Your name cannot be made up of numbers");
       isIntString = false; // to prevent going into this block again
       Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
       name = Console.ReadLine();
  }
```